# How to apply where clause on field of related table on Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have following query that I need to achieve in Laravel eloquent:

```
SELECT Q.quoteid
FROM `tblquote` Q
INNER JOIN tbladdress A ON A.addressid = Q.addressid
INNER JOIN tblquotecompany QC ON QC.quoteid = Q.quoteid
INNER JOIN tblcompany C ON C.companyid = QC.companyid
WHERE 
Q.useremail = 'test@test' or 
(Q.ipaddress = '000.00.00.' and A.zipcode = '00000')
```

I have all relation set up in laravel.

I am trying to achieve this like below:

```
$this->eloquentQuote->newQuery()
                    ->with(EloquentQuote::RELATION_ADDRESS)
                    ->with(EloquentQuote::RELATION_QUOTE_COMPANIES . '.' . EloquentQuoteCompany::RELATION_COMPANY)
                    ->whereHas(EloquentQuote::RELATION_ADDRESS,
                        function ($query) use ($userEmail, $userIp, $zipCode) {
                            /** @var Builder $query */
                            $query->where([
                                [EloquentQuote::USER_EMAIL, '=', $userEmail],
                            ])
                                ->orWhere([
                                    [EloquentQuote::IP_ADDRESS, '=', $userIp],
                                    [EloquentAddress::ZIP_CODE, '=', $zipCode],
                                ]);
                        })->get();
```

This Eloquent query is giving expected result but taking too much time.

Is there any other way to do that efficiently?

Your help is highly regarded.

Comment: how much data do you have? i believe it's normal if there are many data and if you are using string comparisons in your query.

Comment: Use Laravel debugger https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar#installation
which will convert eloquent query into plain SQL. Run plain SQL query with `explain` in phpmyadmin or any other tool

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code will be helpfull for you

```
$result = DB::table('tblquote')
    ->join('tbladdress', 'tbladdress.addressid', 'tblquote.addressid')
    ->join('tblquotecompany', 'tblquotecompany.quoteid', 'tblquote.quoteid')
    ->join('tblcompany', 'tblcompany.companyid', 'tblquotecompany.companyid')
    ->where('tblquote.useremail', 'test@test')
    ->orWhere([['tblquote.ipaddress','000.00.00.'], ['tbladdress.zipcode', '00000']])
    ->get();
```